# string manipulation- middle 3 letters

Tags: java, string, mutation

After prompting for a string, I am trying to display the middle three characters of that string. How would I do that?

this is what I tried:

```
String middle3 = (string.length < 3) ? null : string.substring(string.length / 2 - 1), string.length / 2 + 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

`length` is a **method** of the [String class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29), so you need to use `()`:

```
String middle3 = (string.length() < 3) ? null : 
              string.substring(string.length() / 2 - 1, string.length() / 2 + 2);
```

Comment: I think you mean: string.substring(string.length() / 2 - 1, 3);

Comment: Ok, how would I simplify the process?

Comment: this will throw NPE if string is null

Answer (score 0):

This will work for any string that is odd, length > 3

```
String word = "Hello";
int midCharsStart = ((word.length() + 1) / 2) - 2;
int midCharsEnd = midCharsStart + 3;
System.out.println(word.substring(midCharsStart, midCharsEnd));
```